# Android - ListView objects being duplicated every time the MainActivity loads

Tags: android, listview

I have 20 contacts in a list and you can click on each one to go to their detail view. However, upon going back to the list, the same 20 contacts are added in again. I understand that the onCreate() code is just being executed again, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //ArrayList<contact> contacts = new ArrayList<contact>();

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String s;
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("contacts.json");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        s = sb.toString();


        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            contact c = new contact(); // Creates an empty contact object
            phone p = new phone(); // Creates an empty phone object
            // Retrieves contact information from JSONObject
            String detailsURL = obj.getString("detailsURL"); 
            String name = obj.getString("name");
            int employeeId = obj.getInt("employeeId");
            String company = obj.getString("company");              
            String imageURL = obj.getString("smallImageURL");
            long birthdate = obj.getLong("birthdate");
            JSONObject phone = obj.getJSONObject("phone");
            String workPhone = phone.getString("work");
            String homePhone = phone.getString("home");
            if(phone.has("mobile")){
                    String mobilePhone = phone.getString("mobile");
                    p.setMobilePhone(mobilePhone);
            }
            //Sets contact values to retrieved JSON data and adds to the ArrayList
            c.setName(name);
            c.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
            c.setCompany(company);
            c.setImageURL(imageURL);
            c.setBirthdate(birthdate);
            p.setWorkPhone(workPhone);
            p.setHomePhone(homePhone);
            c.setPhone(p);
            c.setDetailsURL(detailsURL);

            contacts.add(c);
          }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("contact", "file");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("contact", "IO");
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, contacts);
    list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailView.class);
                intent.putExtra("contact", i);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: the JSON streaming looks like a candidate to be moved to an AsyncTask btw.

Comment: Yeah, that'll be moved there soon, thanks!

Comment: onCreate is not calling again. According to Activity lifecycle, when you left your activity for showing the details the activity goes to Pause state, and when you are coming back to the activity the onResume method will get called not onCreate. onCreate is only called once in a lifetime of an activity That means the problem is not in your onCreate method when you pushing the data into listview or while you are generating the data arraylist. i think the data is get added every time you comming back to your activity. you have to make sure the data is added only one time into your data arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the snippet that populates your `ListView` by putting a `boolean` controller that checks if it already has been populated.

```
boolean listViewPopulated = false;

if (!listViewPopulated) {
  // Populate your ListView
  ...
  listViewPopulated = true;
}
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Try something like this:

```
class YourClass extends WhatEver {
  boolean listViewPopulated = false;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!listViewPopulated) {
      //ArrayList<contact> contacts = new ArrayList<contact>();

      BufferedReader br = null;

      try {
        String s;
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("contacts.json");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        s = sb.toString();


        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
          for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            contact c = new contact(); // Creates an empty contact object
            phone p = new phone(); // Creates an empty phone object
            // Retrieves contact information from JSONObject
            String detailsURL = obj.getString("detailsURL"); 
            String name = obj.getString("name");
            int employeeId = obj.getInt("employeeId");
            String company = obj.getString("company");              
            String imageURL = obj.getString("smallImageURL");
            long birthdate = obj.getLong("birthdate");
            JSONObject phone = obj.getJSONObject("phone");
            String workPhone = phone.getString("work");
            String homePhone = phone.getString("home");
            if(phone.has("mobile")){
                    String mobilePhone = phone.getString("mobile");
                    p.setMobilePhone(mobilePhone);
            }
            //Sets contact values to retrieved JSON data and adds to the ArrayList
            c.setName(name);
            c.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
            c.setCompany(company);
            c.setImageURL(imageURL);
            c.setBirthdate(birthdate);
            p.setWorkPhone(workPhone);
            p.setHomePhone(homePhone);
            c.setPhone(p);
            c.setDetailsURL(detailsURL);

            contacts.add(c);
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("contact", "file");
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("contact", "IO");
      }

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, contacts);
      list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailView.class);
                intent.putExtra("contact", i);
                startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
      }

   listViewPopulated = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which snippet exactly? I put it around the 4 lines starting with `setContentView` and the same problem persists.

Comment: I mean to wrap the piece of code that populates your `ListView`, not the `setContentView` statement.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that be my getView method? But that needs to execute a number of times to populate the list first, not just once

Comment: The `getView()` method is ok, I think these two lines should be enough to wrap with these boolean controller:  `myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, contacts); list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);`

Comment: Same issue occurs unfortunately

Comment: I think it's being set back to true for some reason afterwards. I have it printing into my Log and it's always false when the ListView initializes.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what I meant. I don't know if the brackets match as I cannot test it right now but that's the idea. I mean: You have to initialize the `boolean` value **outside** the `onCreate` method or it will be overwritten each time and probably that's what you're seeing, so do it at declaration time in your class. The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is contacts a static member of your activity, and statically initialized?
If it is it's not a big mystery since it is only initialized once when the process is created, not the activity, and you keep adding the same contacs with each onCreate.

-- EDIT --

Since the culprit is contacts and not the ListView the simple solution will be to add a condition before the try/catch block:

```
if (contacts.isEmpty())
    try {
        ...
    }
```

The rest of the, setting adapter and onclick listener should still be executed.

Comment: I needed to make it static so that I could access the ArrayList in other views

Comment: That is fine, but you didn't have to create it statically, or you could check if it's empty.